# Получение кол-ва строк через COUNT

Tags: php, mysql, count

Всем привет. Пытаюсь посчитать кол-во строк через вот такую комбинацию:

```
$alllog = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vk');

echo "$alllog";
```

В итоге получаю:

> Resource id #5

Знаю, что делаю что-то не так, но не понимаю что. 
Прописываю `$db = new safemysql();` и повторяю тот же запрос, только `$db->mysql_query` выдает ошибку.
Что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: Мануал откройте хотя бы. Может увидите там что расширением mysql_ уже никто не пользуется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Для запросов SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN и других запросов,
> возвращающих результат из нескольких рядов, [mysql_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php) возвращает
> дескриптор результата запроса ([resource](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.resource.php)), или FALSE в случае ошибки

Вы пытаетесь вывести дескриптор результата запроса, вместо того, чтобы сделать правильно через `mysql_fetch_assoc`(и т.п.) или просто через `mysql_num_rows`.

Пример:

```
$alllog = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM vk');
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($alllog);
echo $row["count"];
```

---

**Теперь о важном**:

> Данное расширение(mysql) [устарело](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php), начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удалено в
> PHP 7.0.0. Используйте вместо него [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) или [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-mysql.php). Смотрите
> также инструкцию [MySQL: выбор API](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) и [соответствующий FAQ](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) для получения
> более подробной информации.
>
> Альтернативы для данной функции:
>
> [mysqli_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php)
>
> [PDO::query()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.query.php)

Comment: @rjhdby да, ошибки в этом нет

Comment: огромное спасибо, храни вас бог

Comment: @palenkov пожалуйста) Для того, чтобы отметить ответ принятым, нажмите на серую галку рядом с ответом. Галка станет зелёной. Это будет означать, что ответ [отмечен как решение Вашего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: а не подскажете, как сделать еще один каунт(просто с WHERE), $row может быть лишь одна

Comment: @palenkov не совсем понял вопрос, уточните подробнее. пример запроса с `where`: `SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM vk WHERE id = '1'`